# How to get NPM reactify working globally?

Tags: reactjs

I can get the NPM module reactify working locally, but when install globally as: `npm install -g reactify` it's not getting found.

Comment: how are you trying to use it globally?

Comment: Like this `watchify --debug -t reactify ./app.jsx -o ./build/app-brow.js`, I want to NOT include the reactify code in the app-brow.js file.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to figure out how to make the app-brow.js file smaller, it's to 2MB, before minification, 427KB after minification. My JS code is only 10KB, + react + react-router + reactify, not using any other JS libs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global npm installs are for command line tools.  You want to do a local install.

For the size issue:

```
NODE_ENV=production browserify -t reactify myapp.js | uglifyjs -m > myapp.min.js
```

This will produce a file ~170kb, however it gzips to about 45kb, which is the only size that matters.

```
$ du -h myapp.*
1.5M      myapp.debug.js
164K      myapp.min.js
 44K      myapp.min.js.gz
```

If reactify is in your bundle, you're doing something wrong.  You shouldn't ever need to require() it, except in js based build scripts (which also don't end up in your bundle).

If you're compiling with the --debug flag, you have to expect the file size to be bigger.  It actually includes character source maps for all of the files you depend on, and there's no minification, and all of the react debug code is still present (the NODE_ENV thing allows that to be removed by minifiers).

Comment: Yeah, I overlooked the --debug flag.